# How to change view visibility at parent fragment from child fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am using nested fragment that have hierarcy looks like this :
MainActivity>parent fragment> child fragment.
mainactivity hold few parent fragment like fragment10,fragment11,fragment12.
and on parent fragment hold few fragment too like fragmentinti,fragmentdasar,fragmentindikator.
At fragment10 i hv relativelayout that blocking listview, the recyclerview is showing information if i dont hv data.
At fragmentinti i hv process that getting from API if hv data relativelayout on the fragment10 must be setvisibility GONE.

I have trying to use some code at stackoverflow but its still give me an error,

first code that i tested

```
fragmentKelas10 = (fragmentKelas10) getParentFragment();
fragmentKelas10.getView().findViewById(R.id.nodata).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

second

```
fragmentKelas19 parentFrag = ((fragmentKelas10)fragmentKompetensiInti.this.getParentFragment());
parentFrag.setVisibilityNoData(View.GONE);
```

third

```
(fragmentkelas10 getparentfragment()).setvisivity(View.GONE);
```

and on my parentfragment i add public method

```
public void setVisibilityNoData(int visibility){
        nodata.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
```

*nodata is relativelayout

all above code that i tried return error message like this

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View edu.stikom.molearn.fragment.fragmentKelas10.getView()' on a null object reference

Comment: According to exception your fragment is null. Make sure getParentFragment() is not returning null.

Comment: I have read that too @zoe. Even that possible duplicate, still doesn't give me the answer. What i need to know for now is how to use getparentfragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make The activity or fragment you want to return to implement OnFragmentInteractoinLister and when on no data gets called it can return to that fragment or activity and you can hide whatever you want.

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
      public void onNoData() {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onFragmentInteraction();
            }
        }
    @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
                mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            mListener = null;
        }

        public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

            void onFragmentInteraction();
        }
```

Comment: This in not the real answer that i need, But this answer give me an inspiration, thanks anyway.